# what is the counter example to minimality of coloring a graph in BFS manner?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

i was thinking of below algorithm

i use a queue Q to performs BFS and i use an arbitrary start vertex s.
each vertex v has attribute v.color which specifies it's color.

```
 set all vertex colors to 0 
 colorsUsedSoFar = emptyset 
 s.color = 1
 colorsUsedSoFar U {1}
 Q = emptyset
 Q.push(s)

 while(Q != empty){   
   vertex u = Q.pop()
   for each node v adjacent to u{
     (if v.color == 0){
       v.color = color from the set colorsUsedSofar but NotUsedByItsAdjacents
       use the color with minimum number .

       If all the colors in colorsUsedSofar are used by adjacents, assign
       a new color to v and add it to colorsUsedSofar

       Q.push(v)
 }   
}
```

would you give a counter example for it's minimality and show what goes wrong ?

Comment: BFS is fast (low degree polynomial time) and chromatic number (even for $k=3$) is NP-complete... so this algorithm is quite unlikely to succeed (unless P=NP and nobody has tried this before).  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity

Comment: Your algorithm is not specific. *Which* colour from the set colorsUsedSofar but NotUsedByItsAdjacents?

Comment: actually Petersen graph is a counter example regardless of which vertex we start with .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two difficulties that causes the algorithm to fail: the order the colors are selected in is not specified, the order that neighbors of a vertex are colored is not specified.  As an example, here is how it fails:

$V(G)=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and

$E(G)=\{(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (4,5), (3,5), (3,6), (5,6)\}$ (three triangles that pairwise intersect at a vertex... a planar graph with 4 triangular faces).

Vertex 1: Red (neighbors added 2 then 3): ToBeColored $TBC=[2,3]$

Vertex 2: Blue (neighbors added 4, then 5): $TBC=[3, 4, 5]$

Vertex 3: Green (neighbors 5, and add 6): $TBC=[4, 5, 6]$

Vertex 4: Red (neighbors 5... already added): $TBC=[5, 6]$

Vertex 5: BLACK (neighbors 6... already added): $TBC=[6]$

Vertex 6: Red

This took 4 colors, but can be easily done in 3.

the algorithm produces the coloring

[image]

while the optimal coloring is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let the first vertex $A$ have three neigbours $B,C,D$. Let each of these have another neighbour $B',C',D'$. Join $B',C',D'$ be edges.

If your algorithm starts at $A$, it assigns colour $1$ to $A$, then the same new colour $2$ to $B$,$C$, an $D$. This makes $B,C,D$ indistinguishable for the rest of the algorithm, i.e., we essentially colour a $K_4$ with vertices $B',C',D'$, and $(B=C=D)$ as fourth vertex. This requires four colours.

But if we colour $A, B'$ red, $B,C,D'$ green, and $D,C'$ blue, we use only $3$ colours.

Comment: what you mean by "Join B′,C′,D′ be edges"